# Same action call on on Button in ember cli,But actions are different

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have two actions wirte in controller of ember cli and two buttons in template handelbar,First when i clicked first button(**confirm**) then resource hit(POST request) properly and when we Send PUT request on Second Button(**Cancel**)...when i click, then it hits only **POST REQUEST** ,Which i previously hit request **i.e POST REQUEST**. But when we do browser referesh then.It works properly(**PUT REQUEST** On **CANCEL BUTTON**). i am using ember-cli 1.12 version helping out.

```
Template.hbs

<button class="pointer btn btn-xs btn-dark-default shadow-btn" {{action 'confirmGrn' grn}}>Confirm</button>

<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger-default shadow-btn" {{action 'cancelGrn' grn}}>CANCEL</button>


controller.js

cancelGrn:function(item){
        console.log('this is cancel request');
       var self = this;
       item.set('isDelete',true);
       item.set('amountType',"NONE");
        item.save().then(function() {
            self.notifications.showSuccess("GRN Cancel Request Sent",      {
                location: "top",
                delay: true,
                autoClose: true
            });
            self.get('grns').reload();

        });

    },

  confirmGrn: function(grn){
        console.log('this is confirm grn');
        var self = this;
        grn.set('updateType', "CONFIRM");
        this.get('modalHelper').openModal('modals/grn-confirmation-modal', {
            entityUpdatedCallback: function(model){
                self.notifications.showSuccess("Products Moved to inventory Successfully", {
                    location: "top",
                    delay: true,
                    autoClose: true
                });
                self.get('grns').reload();
            },
            title: "Confirm GRN",
            existingModel: grn
        });
    },
```

Comment: You havent included `confirmGrn` method code

Comment: I have updated post

Comment: Are your functions within the `actions` property in your controller? Did you use the quoted notation in your template (e.g. `{{action 'confirmGrn grn}}` )?

Comment: I have  already added actions in quoted notation in post

Comment: Sorry, but can you try to rephrase your question? I would love to help, but I just can't understand what your problem is. Maybe you can try to use a [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..probelm is solved